# How to Install a Custom Made (Unofficial) Version of Python in an Anaconda or Miniconda Environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-7, conda, miniconda

I am an AI artist and running several AI scripts on a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit computer. Everything is working fine, and I have absolutely no intention to upgrade to Windows 10, or run a virtual machine of Windows 10 inside Windows 7.

The highest version of Python supported by Windows 7, is Python 3.8. If I need to run Python 3.9 and above, the official interpreters won't work, I need to install a custom made (unofficial) version of Python created by a dude called 'adang1345' on GitHub.

**Here is the link of GitHub, where you can download modified version of exe, embeddable, and NuGet installers of Python.**

github.com/adang1345/PythonWin7/tree/master

When I install these unofficial versions of Python directly to the computer, everything is working fine on Windows 7.

**The question is, how do I install these unofficial versions of Python to an Anaconda or Miniconda environment?**

Every time, when I type:
`conda create -n myenv python=3.10`
It automatically downloads the official version of python 3.10 and have it installed in the env. I don't want that.

Anaconda or Miniconda is such an important tool, as you need them to "conda install" many packages that can not be installed using the normal "pip install". Therefore, being able to install an unofficial Python in a conda env is mission critical.

So, how?

> Tried to install the exe file and then created a venv virtual environment, it worked perfectly. However, it is Python environment, not a conda environment, therefore you can not use "conda install", what a bummer!

Comment: On first glance, I'd maybe try writing a Conda recipe to package these special Python builds into a Conda packages. Upload the results to an Anaconda Cloud user channel and then install them via Conda. However, my main worry with this is that some compiled Conda packages will be linked against `libpython*.dll` and may have symbol references missing from the builds you use (depends on toolchain). I'm not hopeful - I suspect you've committed yourself to compile everything.